# how to get the value in dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get the value of this array:

```
Array
(

    [0] => 20
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 22
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 23
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 52
                            [1] => 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to get this values: 20, 21, 22, 23 and 52.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Which value? Which array? There are 4!

Comment: i want to get the value: 20, 21, 22, 23 and 52

Comment: You want to get *all values* out of the array? That's usually called [flattening an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I want to get this values: 20, 21, 22, 23 and 52.*

Translated as getting an array of all values of an original array recursively.  Using standard **[array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)** function...

```
$test_array = array(
    20,
    array(
        21,
        22,
        array(
            23,
            array(
                52,
                null
                )
            )
        )
    );

$array_extracted = array();

array_walk_recursive($test_array, function($val, $key) use (&$array_extracted) {if (!is_array($val)) $array_extracted[] = $val;});

print_r($array_extracted);
/*
gives: Array
(
    [0] => 20
    [1] => 21
    [2] => 22
    [3] => 23
    [4] => 52
    [5] =>
)
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should do it:

```
function flatten_array($a)
{
    $retval = array();
    foreach ($a as $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
            $retval = array_merge($retval,flatten_array($value));
        else
            $retval []= $value;
    }
    return $retval;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to return $retval.

Comment: @RabidFire @Jacob Relkin: It was late for work... again. Here it is.